# Pass bundle whitout starting Activity

Tags: android, arraylist, bundle

I need to pass an ArrayList to an activity, so i can list it out there , but i dont want to start that activity, right then. I need to start the list out activity on an another "Show scanned list" button push. Cause the button on that i want to put the bundle passing only contains a finish(), which i use to go back to my main menu when i got my list ready, and from that menu i go on the show list button.Which starts another activity, the only way i know how to pass a bundle is an intent. But that would start the menu Activity again. I hope some one can understand the problem, i could need some help here.

Thank you in front.

--EDIT--

```
package org.example.sudoku;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.content.Intent;



public class Sudoku extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

     // Set up click listeners for all the buttons

        View exitButton = findViewById(R.id.exit_button);
        exitButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        View scanButton = findViewById(R.id.scan_button);
        scanButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        View editButton = findViewById(R.id.about_button);
        editButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    }
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.scan_button:
            Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
            intent.putExtra("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN.SCAN_MODE", "ONE_D_MODE");
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        break;
        case R.id.about_button:
            ArrayList<String> scanList = new ArrayList<String>();
            scanList.add("asd");
            scanList.add("asd2");
            scanList.add("asd3");
            //String[] names = new String[] { "Linux", "Windows7", "Eclipse", "Suse", "Ubuntu", "Solaris", "Android", "iPhone"};
            Intent about = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(),About.class);
            Bundle b = new Bundle();

            b.putStringArrayList("key", scanList);


            about.putExtras(b);
            startActivityForResult(about, 0);
        break;
        case R.id.exit_button:
            finish();
        break;


                    }
                }



    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        if (requestCode == 0) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
                // Handle successful scan
                Intent result = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(),Result.class);
                Bundle b = new Bundle();
                b.putString("content",contents);
                result.putExtras(b);
                startActivityForResult(result, 0);



            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                // Handle cancel
            }
        }
    }

}
```

this is my main activity. I dont know if i understand right, but i just need another public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) that will handle the finished C activity, which was called by the B activity? And the A one will know that is the B activity cause of the identifier?
I hope i got it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So if i understood the question you have the following situation. You have Activity A from which you've started Activity B (in which you generate the desired ArrayList) then you finish() activity B and from activity A you want to start activity C with the generated list.
If this is your scenario the best approach will be to use activity result. In activity B call http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setResult(int, android.content.Intent) which accepts bundle and pass the ArrayList back to Activity A. Then when you're starting Activity C pass it.

You have to start the Activity B by calling http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent, int) and handle the result in onActivityResult()

Comment: I didn't know you could send back an `Intent` as well. Awesome!

Comment: Also, +1 for understand the asker. I didn't.

Comment: u got it right, but i forgot to tell something else, now there is the A activity, that calls the B activity which is the barcode scanner, that calls the C activity with where i can see the scanned code, and i can push next or the finish button, this C activity is handling the arraylist, now when i press finish i go back to A activity, and the on show list i want to see the scanned list on my D activity. Is there any sulotion?

Comment: Yes just use the same approach. Use setActivity result to return the result to the activity that originally started you.

Comment: is there any, example beside the developer.android page? Cause im rly new to android, and thank you for the answer.

Comment: I posted my thoughts under the edit row, can you check it if im right?

Answer (score 0):

You need to rethink your approach. You will not be able to "work" with an ArrayList inside an Activity w/o going through the onCreate(); It sounds like you need another activity or class that can deal with your ArrayList.

Comment: ah yea i thought about that, so when i call my activity the arraylist is created again, and will be empty?

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to do this seems to be passing your list as an extra in a [FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP) intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("list", myList);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

This would happen when your user presses the button. `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` will finish all of the activities that are on top of `MainActivity` so that you don't need to worry about calling `finish()`. It will also restart `MainActivity`, and you would read your data back in its `onCreate` method.